# How to install android SDK tools without installing Android studio on ubuntu?

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu-16.04, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-manager

I was trying to install Android SDK with the help of the SDK command line tools downloaded from the link https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-3859397.zip on my Linux Ubuntu 16.04 PC.
i run the command following command for installation

```
./android update sdk  
sudo ./android update sdk
```

but getting the this
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMVxG.png)

how to solve this error ?or suggest me a proper way to install build tools.

FYI

and also i read that **~/.android** should contain **androidtool.cfg** file which has below data in it.

```
   http.proxyPort=proper_port

   http.proxyHost=Proper_proxy_ip

   sdkman.show.update.only=true

   sdkman.ask.adb.restart=false

   sdkman.force.http=true
```

Comment: have a look at this: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager.html

Answer (score 0):

It says that `android` script is deprecated, so you must use `$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager --update` for update all the installed packages, and `$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager --list` for see a list of installed, updates and available packages.
See more options at: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager.html or with `$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager --help`

`$ANDROID_HOME` refer to the location of your Android SDK. by example:

`export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/android/sdk`